# Maven not running with Java 10: Files\Java\jdk-10""=="" was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, maven, java-10

I'm trying to upgrade my application to Java 10, so, I installed the JDK and set JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Users\pupeno\app>echo %JAVA_HOME%
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10"

C:\Users\pupeno\app>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe --version
javac 10
```

but no matter what I try to do with Maven, I get the same error:

```
C:\Users\pupeno\app>mvn package
Files\Java\jdk-10""=="" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\pupeno\app>mvn --help
Files\Java\jdk-10""=="" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\pupeno\app>cd ..

C:\Users\pupeno>mvn --help
Files\Java\jdk-10""=="" was unexpected at this time.
```

What does that error mean? What's going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: Just in case, the original linked question(i.e. setting correct JAVA_HOME) doesn't help, please feel free to update the question and reopen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The messages start with "Files\Java\jdk-10" which seems to indicate you have not quoted your `JAVA_HOME` correctly. The correct syntax would be something like

```
set "JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

And then

```
java -version
```

should function without specifying additional arguments on the command line (as should maven).

Answer (score 2):

The quotes shouldn't be part of the `JAVA_HOME` value. You can try following in Windows terminal to confirm it:

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10
mvn --help
```